# How to execute multiple custom animation functions synchronously in Swift 4

Tags: swift, animation, mapkit, completionhandler

I am working on an IOS App that is supposed to help people in a tourist region to make sense of means of transport. To make it crystal clear to them how to get from A to B, routes are animated with Annotation objects. For example once the user chooses to see the route from A to D, a cable car object slides from A to B. Once it finishes, a Shuttle Bus object moves along a road from B to C, followed by a boat sliding from C to D.

So I wrote the following functions.
This one lets a transportMode object (small image of a boat, cable car, etc.) slide in a straight line from A to B or B to A.

```
func animateLinearRoute(transportMode: TransportAnnot, startcoor: 
    CLLocationCoordinate2D, destcoor: CLLocationCoordinate2D){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations:
        {
            if (transportMode.coordinate.latitude == startcoor.latitude && transportMode.coordinate.longitude == startcoor.longitude) {
            transportMode.coordinate = destcoor
        } else {
            transportMode.coordinate = startcoor
        }

    })
}
```

For moving an object along a nonlinear route (usually a road) drawn on a map I use the following function:

```
// pass mode of transport and coordinates along the travel route
func animateNonLinearRoute(transportMode: TransportAnnot, animroute: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]){
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    // get start point of route from coordinates and start drawing route
    let point = self.mapView.convert(animroute[0], toPointTo: self.mapView)
    path.move(to: point)
    // translate each coordinate along the route into a point in the view for drawing
    for coor in animroute {
        let point = self.mapView.convert(coor, toPointTo: self.mapView)
        path.addLine(to: point)
    }

    // create keyframe animation to move annotation along the previously drawn path
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.path = path.cgPath
    animation.duration = 5.0
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    let transportview = self.mapView.view(for: transportMode)
    transportview?.layer.add(animation, forKey: "animate position along path")
    transportMode.coordinate = animroute[animroute.count - 1]
    CATransaction.commit()

}
```

Now the full route can consist of an arbitrary chain of these methods. For example the user may chose to get to a point that requires a linear route -> nonlinear route -> linear route -> nonlinear -> nonlinear.

Ultimately the animations need to be executed in a strictly consecutive manner so the user won't be confused (the second animation should not start unless the first one has finished, etc.).

One consideration would be a keyframe animation like this:

```
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 8, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeLinear, animations: {

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 5/8, animations: {
            self.animateNonLinearRoute(transportMode: self.bus, animroute: self.br.coordinates)
        })

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 5/8, relativeDuration: 3/8, animations: {
            self.animateLinearRoute(transportMode: self.cableCar, startcoor: self.lowerstation, destcoor: self.midstation)
        })

        // dynamically fill up as needed using appropriate relative start times and durations

    }, completion: nil)
```

That doesn't execute the code synchronously though. I guess it conflicts with the timings and keyframes defined within the functions.

I've been messing around with custom completion closures and then put each method in the completion closure of the previous one as well as with dispatch queues. But I don't really seem to understand them because I wasn't able to achieve the desired effects. And as routes get longer nested completion closures don't seem to be an ideal option as they make the program unnecessarily complex. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I traced down the problem.
Since animateNonLinearRoute triggers an animation on the CALayer, the function returns after triggering the animation without waiting for its completion. Therefore all functions in the methods completion handler will be executed, after the CALayer Animation HAS BEEN TRIGGERED, NOT AFTER IT HAS FINISHED.
A simple hacky solution would be to wrap the functions that should be executed after the CALayer Animations have finished, into a CATransaction block:

```
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        self.animateLinearRoute(transportMode: self.cableCar, startcoor: self.lowerstation, destcoor: self.midstation)
    })

    self.animateNonLinearRoute(transportMode: self.bus, animroute: self.br.coordinates)
    CATransaction.commit()
```

I would love to hear a better explanation from someone who understands multithreading and concurrency in Swift and a suggestion for a clean way to chain several of these function calls.